# How does 稱's 2021 meanings appertain to its semantic component 禾?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

[CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%A8%B1) doesn't expound the semantic shift from 禾. I   underlined definition 4 below in green, because I know that rice and grains may need to be weighed. But I don't understand how  definition 4 relates to the other definitions. When you weigh something, you're reporting a rational number. Weighing something differs from calling, naming, commend, praising something.    [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E7%A8%B1#).

[image]

*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* 2003 edn. p 104.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> How does 稱's 2021 meanings appertain to its semantic component 禾?

The meanings which aren't related to *weighing* are not really related to 「禾」 - these meanings were actually held by 「爯」. 「稱」 and 「爯」 are related by the following:

- 「稱」 is a complexification of 「爯」.
- 「爯」 originally meant *to lift up*. This was eventually semantically extended to *to commend, to praise*, then *to call, to name*.
- 「爯」 later acquired the meaning *to weigh*.
- 「爯」 has now been totally replaced by 「稱」, so 「稱」 has acquired most/all senses of what was originally represented by 「爯」.

---

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: 爯] | [鐵](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)102.2 [合集7395](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=7395&jgwfl=) |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: 爯] | 裘衛盉 [集成9456](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9456&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) 金 | [image: 爯] | 者⿰水尸鎛 [集成123](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=123&jgwfl=) |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image: 爯] | [冓部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=2) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 爯] |  |

「爯」 depicts a [*hand* 「爫・爪」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=149) grabbing a [*fish* 「魚」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jiaguwen?kaiOrder=2447) upwards (e.g. out of the water), indicating the original meaning *to lift up, to raise up*. Occasionally, 「爯」 was complexified with extra components, which don't survive today.

<kbd>[image: ⿱爯又]</kbd>

The meaning *to lift up, to raise up* is given in e.g. [《甲骨文合集》32420](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=32420&jgwfl=):

[image: 《甲骨文合集》32420]

> 丁戼（卯）鼎（貞）：「／
> 王（其）爯（琡），／
> 尞（燎）三，／
> 戼（劉）...... 牢？／
> 」
>
> [Divination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone#Shang_divination) on the day of [*dīngmǎo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%81%E5%8D%AF), it is asked: "Shall the king **offer up** a ceremonial jade weapon, conduct a burning ritual with three penned sheep, and perform a slaughtering ritual......penned cattle?"

Very early on, 「爯」 or its variations started also acquiring the meaning *to weigh*. From the Late [Warring States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period) [State of Jìn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state)) artefact 信安君鼎[《殷周金文集成》2773](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2773&jgwfl=):

[image: 《殷周金文集成》2773]

> ⿰言身（信）安君厶（私）官／
> （容）⿱八斗（㪵）／
> ⿱罒氏（視）叓（事）欨、⿰⿱冫火刂（冶）癐／
> 十二秊（年）／
> ⿱爯又（稱・秤）二益（鎰）六釿／
>
> [[*DǏNG* VESSEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ding_(vessel))] OF THE BUTLER FOR [THE LORD OF XÌN'ĀN](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E4%BF%A1%E5%AE%89%E5%90%9B)
> **Vessel capacity:** [half](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%AA%B5) a [*dǒu*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%96%97#Definitions)
> **Officer on duty:** 欨
> **Vessel bronzesmith:** 癐
> **[Date:]** Year 12
> **Vessel weight:** 2 [*yì*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%8E%B0#Han_character) and 6 *jīn*

Since 「爯」 had taken up too many meanings, semantic components were sometimes piled on to the character to disambiguate the uses:

- 「偁」 was created emphasise the meaning *to lift, raise > to praise*, by drawing a [*person* 「人」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=9) behind the *hand* 「爫・爪」:

  <kbd>商
  金
  [image: 偁]
  偁缶作且癸
  [集成3601](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3601&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image: 偁]
  戜者鼎
  [集成2662](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2662&jgwfl=)</kbd>
  <kbd>篆
  [image: 偁]
  [人部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=6)
  說文解字</kbd>
  <kbd>楷
  [image: 偁]</kbd>
- 「稱」 was created by adding semantic 「禾」 (*crops*), as weighing crops and grain from harvest was a common and important activity in Ancient China.

Unfortunately, the character 「偁」 fell into disuse, so 「稱」 in turn also became overloaded. This was probably the major reason for the creation of 「秤」, which is only used for meanings to do with *weighing, balance, scales*, and not used for the overloaded meanings *to raise, to praise, to call* that 「稱」 had taken on.

---

**References:**

- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 何琳儀《戰國古文字典：戰國文字聲系》
- [陳劍《說殷墟甲骨文中的「玉戚」》](http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/902)
- [小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw)

  - [字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
  - [甲骨文](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jiaguwen)
  - [金文](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen)
  - [異體字表](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/variants)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)
- [中國哲學書電子化計劃](https://ctext.org/)

  - [宋・徐鉉等奉敕校定　漢・許慎《說文解字》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&res=77351)

Answer (score 1):

*Outlier*

> **FORM**
> 稱 chēng (also chèng, chèn) is composed of 爯 chēng and 禾 “grain,” which hints at the original meaning “to weigh, measure.” Grain was one of the most commonly measured things in ancient China.
>
> **COMPONENTS**
> 禾
> In 稱, 禾 “grain” is a meaning component, hinting at the original meaning “to weigh, measure.” Grain was one of the most commonly measured things in ancient China.
> 爯
> In 稱 chēng (also chèng, chèn), 爯 chēng is a sound component.
>
> **MEANINGS**
> chēng
> 1 (orig.) to weigh
> 2 → to raise, lift up
> 3 ⇒ to praise, laud
> 4 ⇛ to state, say
> 5 ⭆ to call; name
> 6 → [chèng or chèn] appropriate

This becomes a bit of a *which came first the chicken or the egg*-type of puzzle. Here we can see that *to weigh* was the original meaning associated with this glyph. Then came *to raise/to lift*, which makes sense in relation to how grain would need to be weighed. This was further extended to the definitions of *to praise/to laud*, which is logical in Chinese as being lifted up is often associated with being shown respect or a rise in status. From this came *to state/to say*, and lastly came the meaning of *to call/to name*.

Laying the meanings out like this seems to make it much easier to understand.